# Is this code guaranteed to print all France = Paris?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am a little confused about the happens before guarantees provided by volatile. My understanding is that whatever a thread sees just before reading a volatile field will be seen by another thread that reads the same volatile field afterwards.

By that logic, in following code, the second thread is guaranteed to see the keys that were put by the first thread. Is that understanding correct?

```
public class Capitals{
    static volatile Map<String, String> capitals = new HashMap<>(); 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Thread t = new Thread(()->{
                capitals.put("France", "Paris");
            });
        t.start();
        t.join(); //or Thread.sleep(1000);
        new Thread(()->{
                capitals.forEach((a, b)->System.out.println(a+" = "+b));
            }).start();
        }
}
```

Also, if the capitals field were **not** volatile, or if I use Thread.sleep(1000); there is no guarantee that the second thread will print France = Paris. Right?

Comment: Since `capitals` always points to the same map, the `volatile` keyword isn't relevant here. You're only changing the contents of the map, not replacing it with a new map.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to say? What is the answer to my questions??

Comment: "*the capitals field were **not** volatile*" - does not change anything, since the variable `capitals` is not being changed at all (just the instance it points to.) If `t.join()` is removed, there is no guarantee, but because it is **not** guaranteed that the first thread is run/terminated, and `volatile` will **not** change that (using `Thread.sleep(1000)` makes it *almost* guaranteed to have the first thread executed/terminated)

Comment: @user85421 are you sure that volatile doesn't change anything here? because accessing a volatile forms a memory consistency boundary, no?

Comment: @Priyshrm volatile only provides a happens-before between writes to a volatile variable and subsequent reads of that value. The actual implementation of volatile may provide stronger guarantees, but those are not guaranteed by the Java Memory Model, and those stronger guarantees could vary between implementations, Java versions and platforms, and so those are not something you should rely on.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's guaranteed.

First, the use of `volatile` doesn't make a difference here. That's because you are not changing the value of the `capitals` field. It always points to the same `HashMap`—it's the contents of the map that are changing.

So the real question here is whether your second thread is guaranteed to see changes to the map's contents that were made by the first thread. To answer that question, we can look to the Java Language Specification.

We need to look at [section 17.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5), which describes the concept of "Happens-Before Order".

> Two actions can be ordered by a happens-before relationship. If one action happens-before another, then the first is visible to […] the second.

Later on in the same section, we can find the parts that relate to your question.

> - A call to `start()` on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread.
> - All actions in a thread happen-before any other thread successfully returns from a `join()` on that thread.

The second bullet point lets us know that after the main thread calls `join()`, any changes that were made to the map inside the joined thread will be visible to the main thread too.

And the first bullet point lets us know that the second thread will also see those changes, since it was started by the main thread after that call to `join()`.

Comment: Yes, start of a thread establishes a happens-before but only between main thread and thread 2. Not between thread 2 and thread 1, right? The link between thread 2 and thread 1 is established through volatile, no?

Comment: @Priyshrm The use of `t.join()` establishes a happens-before between thread t and main, and the `start()` establishes a happens-before between main and the new thread, and because of the order of operations (the join happens before the start), that also establishes a happens-before between thread t and the new thread.

Comment: Ok I think I got it - t.join establishes happens-before between thread 1 and main. and start establishes happens-before between  main and thread 2. Hence edits by thread 1 happen before read by thread 2.
What if I remove t.join by thread.sleep? Will volatile be helpful there (assuming that the sleep time is enough to run thread 1)

Comment: @Priyshrm volatile is only relevant if you assign a new value to the variable itself in `t`, and won't help here. There is no such guarantee for `Thread.sleep`, but I suspect it will usually work fine because thread `t` will have ended before the main thread woke up again and started the new thread. However, that is no guarantee for this based on the Java Memory Model (and basically, there is no guarantee that `t` will have ended before the sleep ends, it is just very, very likely).

Comment: Yes, volatile primarily is about changing the reference but it also has a side effect..piggy backing. That is what the last issue left in this question I think.

Comment: Without volatile, any amount of sleep will most likely not work in a multi-cpu system. But with volatile, even a small amount of sleep will most likely work. Is that correct?

Comment: @Priyshrm See also my comment on your question. It may seem to work, because the implementation of volatile may have stronger effects than required by the Java Memory Model, but given no such guarantee is specified by the JMM, you cannot and should not rely on those stronger effects.

Comment: No, not "may", but "must". Volatile does have a piggy backing effect. That's guaranteed by the JMM. That is what I am trying to confirm with this code/question.

Comment: @Priyshrm in that case, can you point to a line in the JLS which describes such a guarantee? I can't find one.

Comment: @Sam Section 17.4.2. Synchronization actions, which are:
– Volatile read. A volatile read of a variable.
– Volatile write. A volatile write of a variable.

Comment: @Priyshrm It only says that a happens-before is established between the write and subsequent reads, see 17.4.4: _"A write to a volatile variable v (§8.3.1.4) synchronizes-with all subsequent reads of v by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order)."_ Given in this case no write happens to the volatile field by `t` (only a _read_!), volatile doesn't provide any guarantees here. Volatile only covers the variable (the reference held), it doesn't cover the object referenced by the variable!

Comment: Right, synchronization action means whatever thread 1 sees before that synchronization action is seen by thread 2. "Whatever" is the key part here. From Brian Goetz's concurrency in practice book:
"The visibility effects of volatile variables extend beyond the value of the
volatile variable itself. When thread A writes to a volatile variable and subsequently thread B reads that same variable, the values of all variables that were
visible to A prior to writing to the volatile variable become visible to B after
reading the volatile variable. "

Comment: "So from a memory visibility perspective, writing
a volatile variable is like exiting a synchronized block and reading a volatile
variable is like entering a synchronized block.  However, we do not recommend
relying too heavily on volatile variables for visibility; code that relies on volatile
variables for visibility of arbitrary state is more fragile and harder to understand
than code that uses locking."

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel, I understand what you are saying. But that is what I am trying to confirm here. From Concurrency in Practice book, I am getting that volatile does ensure visibility of everything prior to a volatile read or write. Not just that particular field.

You believe it does not and I get that. I would like to wait for a second opinion on this.

Comment: @Priyshrm, "From Concurrency in Practice book, I am getting that volatile does ensure visibility of everything prior to a volatile **read** or write." I think you must have misread the book. `volatile` only synchronizes between _a write_ in one thread,  and a subsequent read in a different thread. None of your threads ever writes the volatile variable. So, there is no benefit from using `volatile` in your example.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, you mean to say memory barrier forms only when one thread writes and another reads, and not when one thread reads and another also reads? That means, if I add an empty synchronized block at the end of thread 1 and at be beginning of thread 2 like this synchronized(capitals){}, then that will not work either?
The book in section 16.2.2 says, "Similarly, using a shared variable guarded by a lock or a shared volatile variable ensures that reads and writes of that variable are ordered by happens-before." It says "using". Reading is using. no?

Comment: @Priyshrm, Yes. Reading is "using." But where the JLS describes `volatile` variables, it doesn't say, "using." It explicitly says "read" and "write." It says, "A _write_ to a volatile variable synchronizes with all subsequent _reads..._" Your code example initializes the volatile variable before `main()` is called, but from that point on, no thread ever writes the variable.

Comment: @Priyshrm Adding an empty synchronized block to both threads _could_ establish a happens-before relationship, but only if in the actual execution the synchronization in the writing thread precedes the synchronization in the reading thread. But bar additional concurrency actions (like using thread.join), there would be no guarantee that the writing thread actually runs *before* the reading thread. And if you use thread.join() to enforce order, you wouldn't need that empty synchronization block, because it doesn't add anything extra.

Comment: @Priyshrm And to be clear, we're discussing the guarantees required by the Java Memory Model. In practice you might get stronger effects, but because those aren't guaranteed, you shouldn't rely on nor expect those effects!

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, " but only if in the actual execution the synchronization in the writing thread precedes the synchronization in the reading thread." Right. That part is clear. But if an empty synchronized block in that manner will work then a read of a volatile should work too. That is what I am almost sure about but not completely sure.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel "we're discussing the guarantees required by the Java Memory Model. In practice you might get stronger effects." Absolutely. That is the reason it is difficult or even impossible to test this through a program.

Comment: @Priyshrm No it wouldn't, because there is no write in the thread. Volatile synchronizes between a write in a thread and subsequent reads of that value in other threads (if a thread X writes a value _n_, then a thread Y reading that value _n_ will also see all effects produced by thread X before that write). Given no write happens, there is no happens-before effect established, and you cannot expect any visibility guarantees. You assume the write by itself has memory-visibility effects, it does not, it is the combination of the write and subsequent reads which have memory-visibility effects.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Please see Section 12.6.2 and 17.4.2 of JLS 21. As per 12.6.2: "If x and y are synchronization actions on the same variable or monitor such that
so(x, y) (§17.4.4) and y comes-before di, then x must come-before di." and as per 17.4.2 "Volatile read. A volatile read of a variable" is a synchronization action.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel all actions given in Section 17.4.2 are synchronization actions. Are they not? It doesn't say that a synchronization action is a combination of write + read.

Comment: @Priyshrm All synchronization actions requires two sides. One in the thread producing the effect, and one in the thread wanting to see those effects.  And this is established in section 17.4.4. And in the case of `volatile` reads by itself don't produce a happens-before, only between a _write_ and subsequent _reads_ of that value. And even if it did, the modification in the map you want to see happens **after** the read in thread `t`. So even if a read in t would produce a happens-before with the read in the new thread, the effects you want to see (the change of the map) wouldn't be covered.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Got you. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score -3):

Yes you are correct thread.sleep is working because operation is small and main thread can wait for 1000ms and its enough time to complete operation. same for volatile if inside thread there were multiple  operation we wouldn't have got latest values.

Comment: Sleep provides no such guarantee. It will (seem to) work in general, but it is entirely possible (e.g. on an overloaded machine) that the thread `t` hasn't even run before the sleep ends and the other thread is started.

Comment: `sleep` makes it less likely that a latent defect will manifest as an actual crash/fault/glitch or whatever you want to call it. But in real-world applications, `sleep` also degrades performance. There's a temptation to "tweak" the sleep time—just long enough so that the defect never appears during testing, but not so long as to noticeably slow things down. What happens next is, you release the product to customers, and then, when the defect eventually _does_ show itself, (which, it will) it happens at customer sites, and it ends up costing millions of dollars. (Don't ask me how I know!)