# Different threads updating different attribute of the same object, will it work?

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

I have one method as follows:

```java
public Book enrichBook(Book book) {
  Long bookId = book.getId();

  Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> book.setAuthors(authorService.findByBookId(bookId)));
  Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> book.setPrice(priceService.calcByBookId(bookId)));
  t1.start(); t2.start();
  
  t1.join(); t2.join();
  return book;
}
```

(Note : My book object is just simply object without volatile or synchronized keyword on it)

From a main thread, two threads were created to update different attributes of an object. Thread `t1` updates author attribute, thread `t2` updates price attribute.

I have debugged many times and it works correctly without any problem, but is there any scenario where this code can break or cause strange behavior? For example the final result will only have the updating of one attribute.

My other approach is to use CompletableFutures, does it has the same behavior like the first one when use thread?

```
public Book enrichBook(Book book) {
  Long bookId = book.getId();

  CompletableFuture<Void> authorFuture = CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->  book.setAuthors(authorService.findByBookId(bookId)), appConfig.getAsyncExecutor());
  CompletableFuture<Void> priceFuture = CompletableFuture.runAsync(()-> book.setPrice(priceService.calcByBookId(bookId)), appConfig.getAsyncExecutor());
  
  List<CompletableFuture<Void>> completableFutures = new ArrayList<>();
  completableFutures.add(authorFuture); 
  completableFutures.add(priceFuture);
  
  CompletableFuture<Void> allFuturesResult = CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[completableFutures.size()]));
  allFuturesResult.join(); // try - catch is igored here
  
  return book;
}
```

Will this work or will there be unexpected results?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this code guaranteed to print all France = Paris?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78171114/is-this-code-guaranteed-to-print-all-france-paris)

Comment: based on the linked question: after the main thread calls join(), any changes that were made to the object inside the joined thread should be visible to the main thread too. You seem to be missing a semicolon after t2.start(). Typo?

Comment: yes BIBBO nation. it's just typo. After reading your linked question,  as I understand my code will work correctly because of  the concept "Happens-Before Order", and the change should be visible to main thread and of course the change made by thread t1 also be visible to thread t2. Does this behavior work the same when I use CompletableFuture ? I haved update the new approach with CompletableFuture.

Comment: @BIBOOnation sorry for this inconvenient. But my updated code with CompletableFuture is not in my case, because it's correctly when use CompletableFuture  with supplyAsync. My idea is when use runAsync and now two thread will be updating the object and does it have the same behavior of original thread base solution (I haved update my code and again so sorry for this inconvenient)

Comment: well, i would say both of it looks to achieve a similar result, though i m not too sure about how thread safe your code is.

Comment: Oh my book object is just simply object without volatile or synchronized keywork on it. btw many thanks for giving me your time.

Comment: then that means there could be concurrency issues like data races. what if multiple threads work on the same object?

Comment: yes, and this is what I'm asking and want to clarify more. But in the linked question as you mention , it said that because of the concept "Happens-Before Order",  "the use of volatile doesn't make a difference here" , so I'm thinking my code work correctly without any problem  ?

Comment: No. thats only if for example: thread A is the only one calling enrichBook() on book A. The happens before means that after all the joins, thread A will be able to see the changes made on the book from the two threads it created and joined on. If another thread is calling the method on book A at the same time, there are 2 sets of thread t1 and t2 created by thread A and thread B. and thats where concurrency issues can occur

Comment: See [this short section of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3) for an explanation of why your code will fail.

Comment: @BIBOOnation In my case , there is just only thread calling enrichBook() for a book object. It's just a simple rest api, first find book by id and then calling to enrichBook()

Answer (score -2):

Exclusively changing different plain attributes of an object by different threads has no problem. Of course you cannot be sure about orders of changes per execution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think my answer is clear and precise. The question is about any unexpected result when changing different attributes by different threads and my answer is completely related to the question.